# Save a gradient for future use

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I've produced quite a complex gradient in Ai, is there any way of saving this as a file I can then import to use with other assets in Ai in stead of manually having to reproduce it each time?

Answer (score 5):

You can save a **Swatch Library** from the **Swatch Panel Options**

[image: swatch panel]

If you have several swatches and you want to save just this gradient:

- Copy a shape containing this gradient
- Create a new Illustrator file
- From the **Swatches Panel Options** choose **Select All Unused**
- Delete them clicking the garbage can
- **Paste** the shape with the gradient
- Save the **Swatch Library**

[image]

To recover the **Swatch Library** go to the **Swatches Panel Options** > **Open Swatch Library** > **Other Library** and select the one you need.